# Redirect based upon script output?

Tags: lighttpd

I'd like to redirect "/" based upon the output of a bash script. Say the script returns 0 or 1.

I have inherited a lighttpd server with no experience so hoping someone can help. :)

Basically I want:

```
On accessing any url
     If script output returns 1
         redirect to /index.php
     else
         redirect to another url
```

Is this possible with lighttpd? Trying to avoid spinning up a PHP process for something this simple.

Answer (score 0):

You might (ab)use mod_fastcgi authorizer mode to do this, and have your script return 302 Found with Location: ... to the target URL of your choice.  https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModFastCGI

However, to do this, your script must be a fastcgi script, or you can start it with a wrapper such as spawn-fcgi https://github.com/lighttpd/spawn-fcgi
(or you can write your script in C and use the example code in the Docs_ModFastCGI page above) (or you can use Python and see https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/HowToPythonWSGI )